# How can I modify XIRR to measure different numbers of periods based on where a certain value occurs?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an `XIRR` function that will adjust how many periods it is measuring based on the address of a specific value. For example, if the value occurs in month 48, I want the `XIRR` function to measure 48 columns of data, but if the value occurs in month 17,

I want `XIRR` to only measure 17 columns. I can get the address of the value and the corresponding dates using`=CELL("address", MATCH(...` etc., but I can't figure out how / if I can concatenate the `XIRR` inputs. Initially, I hoped I could do something like:

`=XIRR(A1:Cell("address", [value_reference]), B1:Cell("Address", [date_reference]))`

Can anyone help me with this?  Using Excel 2007

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OFFSET` to make a dynamic range

If for example

- you had values in `A1:A50`
- dates in `B1:B50`
- a specific value in `D2` (that occurs in your values in column A)

Then this formula

`=XIRR(OFFSET(A1,0,0,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$50,0),1),OFFSET($B$1,0,0,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$A$50,0),1))`

will do the dynamic range matching